# Chain rule for vector calculus

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-optimization

I am struggling with this optimisation problem where I have my costfunction $J(\mathbf{x}):\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and analytical gradient $\nabla J(\mathbf{x})=J^\prime(\mathbf{x})$ for input vector $\mathbf{x}$, however the input needs to be normalised with $f(\mathbf{x}):\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$ so my new cost function is $J(f(\mathbf{x}))$ with
$$
f(\mathbf{x})) = \frac{\mathbf{x}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}}}
$$

My question is about the chain rule, 
$$
\nabla J(f(\mathbf{x})) \stackrel{?}{=} J^\prime(f(\mathbf{x})) f^\prime(\mathbf{x})) 
$$
is this valid, and what would my $f^\prime(\mathbf{x})) $ look like? Is it a matrix or a vector?
$$
f(\mathbf{x})) = \frac{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}}-\frac{2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^H}{2\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}}}}{\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}}
$$

Note $\mathbf{x}^H$ is the Hermitian of $\mathbf{x}$, complex numbers are optional here, but will make my life easier later on.

Comment: Where is this computation needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to math.stackexchange.

First, for the chain rule it is better to use the Jacobi matrix instead of the gradient.
We write this as $J'(x)$ or $f'(x)$.
Then the gradient is the transpose of the Jacobi matrix,
so we have to write $\nabla J(x)=J'(x)^H$.

Let us define $g(x)=J(f(x))$ and let $n$ be the length of the vector $x$.
Then the chain rule says 
$$g'(x)=J'(f(x))f'(x),$$
where $x\in\mathbb C^n$, $f'(x)\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$, and $J'(f(x))\in\mathbb C^{1\times n}$.

For the calculation of $f'(x)$ know that the result has to be a $n\times n$-matrix
and that maybe the chain rule might be helpful again.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the case for $x\in{\mathbb R}^{n}$.

First, assign the length of $x$ to its own variable. 
$$\eqalign{
\lambda^2 &= x^Tx \quad\implies\quad \lambda\,d\lambda = x^Tdx \\
}$$
Write down the explicit formula for normalized vector $(f)$ and  calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \lambda^{-1}x \\
df &= \lambda^{-1}dx - x\lambda^{-2}d\lambda \\
 &= \lambda^{-1}dx - x\lambda^{-3}x^Tdx \\
 &= \lambda^{-1}\left(I - ff^T\right)dx \\
 &= \left(\frac{I-ff^T}{x^Tx}\right)dx \\
}$$
Use the gradient of the cost function $J$ with respect to $f$ to write its differential, then perform a change of variables to calculate its gradient with respect to $x$.
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= \left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial f}\right):df \\
 &= \left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial f}\right)
  : \left(\frac{I-ff^T}{x^Tx}\right)dx
\\
 &= \left(\frac{I-ff^T}{x^Tx}\right)\left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial f}\right)
  : dx
\\
\frac{\partial J}{\partial x} 
 &= \left(\frac{I-ff^T}{x^Tx}\right)\left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial f}\right) \\
}$$
**NB:** In some of the steps, a colon is used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \operatorname{Tr}\left(A^TB\right) \\
}$$
In the complex case, you'll need to dive into [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_n_%3E_1_complex_variables) and it's probably not worth the headache.

Besides, the cost function **must be** real, since complex values are not comparable. For example, which complex number is larger $\,(2+3i)$ or $(3-2i)$ ?